# Error al Validar Stock al momento de actualizar una venta

Tags: php, array

Tengo un pequeño bug con un sistema de Ventas, para lo cual muestro y explico primeramente las dos funciones en donde tengo el problema, la siguiente función se ejecuta cuando se agrega detalles a la venta:

```js
//*** Declaración de Variables necesarias para trabajar con las ventas y sus detalles ***//

//*** Valor actual de Impuesto ***//
var impuesto=18;
var cont=0;
var detalles=0;
var cantidad=1;
//*** Función que es invocada por el boton(+) de la ventana modal Articulos ***//
//*** Se encarga de agregar el articulo seleccionado a la ventana detalles de la venta ***//
function agregarDetalle(idarticulo,articulo,stock,precio_venta)
{
   //*** Valores iniciales ***//
    var descuento=0;

    if (idarticulo!="")
    {
     var subtotal=cantidad*precio_venta;
     var fila='<tr class="filas" id="fila'+cont+'">'+
     '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle('+cont+')">X</button></td>'+
     '<td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]" value="'+idarticulo+'">'+articulo+'</td>'+
     '<td><input type="hidden" name="stock[]" id="stock[]" value="'+stock+'">'+stock+'</td>'+
     '<td><input type="number" onchange="modificarSubtotales()" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td>'+
     '<td><input type="number" name="precio_venta[]" id="precio_venta[]" value="'+precio_venta+'"></td>'+
     '<td><input type="number" name="descuento[]" value="'+descuento+'"></td>'+
     '<td><span name="subtotal" id="subtotal'+cont+'">'+subtotal+'</span></td>'+
     '<td><button type="button" onclick="modificarSubtotales()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></td>'+
     '</tr>';
     cont++;
     detalles=detalles+1;
  //*** Codigo que agrega al objeto con el id detalles todo lo que contiene la variable fila ***//
     $('#detalles').append(fila);
     //*** Codigo para actualizar Subtotales desde un primer instante ***//
     modificarSubtotales();
    }
    else
    {
     alert("Error al ingresar el detalle, revisar los datos del artículo");
    }
}
```

La siguiente función se ejecuta cuando se actualizan los detalles o se cambia de valor en el campo `cantidad`:

```js
function modificarSubtotales()
{
   //*** Declarar arrays para almacenar cantidad, precio_compra_subtotal ***//
 //*** Por ejemplo el array cant almacenara todas las cantidades de la venta ***//
   var cant = document.getElementsByName("cantidad[]");
   var stock = document.getElementsByName("stock[]");
    var prec = document.getElementsByName("precio_venta[]");
    var desc = document.getElementsByName("descuento[]");
    var sub = document.getElementsByName("subtotal");
    //*** Recorrer elementos de detalles para actualizar el Subtotal ***//
 //*** El bucle se ejecutara hasta llegar a la cantidad de indices que tiene la variable cant ***//
    for (var i = 0; i <cant.length; i++) {
     
      var inpST=stock[i];
      //*** Variables para almacenar las cantidades de los detalles respecto a sus indices [i] ***//
      var inpC=cant[i];
      var inpP=prec[i];
      var inpD=desc[i];
      var inpS=sub[i];
        //*** Condicional que compara y valida el stock respecto a la cantidad***//
     if (inpST.value >= inpC.value) {
      //*** Actualizar Subtotal ***//
      inpS.value=(inpC.value * inpP.value)-inpD.value;
      document.getElementsByName("subtotal")[i].innerHTML = inpS.value;
      calcularTotales();
      alert("Exito: cant: "+inpC.value+" < stock: "+inpST.value);
     }else{
      alert("Error: cant: "+inpC.value+" > stock: "+inpST.value);
     }
    }
}
```

El problema básicamente es con la condicional que compara el `stock` con la `cantidad` que se está agregando, en teoría si la `cantidad` no supera al `stock` debería de ejecutarse el `alert("exito")` pero esto no sucede por ejemplo dejo una captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la captura, el sistema muestra el `alert("error")`, lo cual no tiene lógica por lo anteriormente mencionado debido a que en ese caso en particular el valor del campo `cantidad` no supera al `stock` entonces el `alert` correcto debería ser el de `alert("exito")`, estoy llegando a creer que el error está en el bucle `for` y no en la condicional, pero ya inspeccione el código para verificar los índices de los detalles que se van agregando y no veo nada extraño.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar esto, y futuros errores en los cálculos, convierte al menos los valores que intervienen en cálculos a entero usando [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
    intST=parseInt(inpST.value,10);
    intC=parseInt(inpC.value,10);
    intP=parseInt(inpP.value,10);
    intD=parseInt(inpD.value,10);


    if (intST >= intC) {
        //*** Actualizar Subtotal ***//
        inpS.value=(intC * intP)-intD;
        document.getElementsByName("subtotal")[i].innerHTML = inpS.value;
        calcularTotales();
        alert("Exito: cant: "+intC+" < stock: "+intST);
    }else{
        alert("Error: cant: "+intC+" > stock: "+intST);
    }
```

---

Si de todos modos no funciona, verifica que no ocurre nada extraño en `calcularTotales();`

Comment: Solved, muchas gracias por la aclaración, desde ahora tomare  muy en cuenta este consejo.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema que el compañero, y no me funciona la solución. Ayuda!!!!

Comment: @Esmanar este problema se resolvió convirtiendo los valores a entero antes de hacer la comparación. Si tu problema no se resuelve así lo mejor será que lo plantees en una nueva pregunta dando más detalles sobre el contexto y poniendo los elementos sobre los que estás trabajando.